# API file upload (Server Side) check if there is an actual file before trying to read it

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an Web-API 2 Post method to upload a physical file to the server. I noticed I could still call that API without passing an actual file.

So when the server side runs these 2 lines of code

```
var sp = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileName);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(sp);
```

When the client (not a browser, not fiddler) calls the API but does not upload a file, I get an exception (that is trapped).

**QUESTION**:
Is there a way to check if the Request carries a file, **BEFORE** calling the `Request.Content.ReasAsMultipartAsync`??

My problem is NOT to trap the exception, but to find a clean way to learn before I get into the exception that there was no file so that I can notify the calling client about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @Radim's response.

Another approach you can take (only if you host your service in IIS only, the default template does it)

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

// Check if files are available
if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
{
```

Note that you are taking a dependency on System.Web here, but if you are on IIS and not self hosting this is fine.

Comment: Yes, it's in IIS. Let me try this.

Comment: I had to add the using System.Web; but I guess that's OK. Thanks.

Comment: Note: you can get the stream directly off the files[0] and so on collection, and don't need to readmultipartasync with this approach

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would suggest to wrap this statement in `try catch`, as shown here: [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2).

```
// Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
{
  throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
}

string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

try
{
  // Read the form data.
  await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

  // TODO ... process files

  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
  return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
}
```

Why to use explicit try catch? We never now *who* and *how* will assemble the http request (Browser, Fiddler, third-party tool) ... and the content could be simply damaged, impossible to handle standard way.

The point with `Async` content readers is, that we **have to read** the content, to get the **answer**:

> **is there any file included?**

That's the way Web API is designed. Read the content only once, only if needed. Before that ... there is no info about the content available.

For example, if there is a request coming from a Browser with a `<form>` like this:

```
<form method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
   action="/api/MyService/Upload">

 <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
 <button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

Then even in case, that we will just submit *(without selecting any file)* part of the request body will be:

```
-----------------------------7de411d9099c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------7de411d9099c--
```

So, until we will **read** we do not know if there is any file

Comment: The call is already wrapped in a try catch. But I will never know if the problem is the actual file uploaded or the fact that there is NO file uploaded. Do you know if the Exception that is raised when no file is present is of a special type?

Comment: My experience is: If there is no file and the request is made by browser (not fiddler etc) then Exception is never thrown. Even in case, that file is missing

Comment: @Radim to get a 500 response - there is no need to wrap and catch, the server will do it for you.

If you want to log or handle specifically for this method then it's probably a good approach, otherwise you can just register an exception filter or use global error handling

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer, well it means, that you do not want to react to that situation. That you will leave it to booble to last exception handler. And in this case, I would say that we should react. Explicitly. And because we have to firstly read the content, we should use EXPLICIT try catch here... But that's how I do that ;)

Comment: The client is NOT a browser ..it's a API client. Exception are costly and I use them ONLY when I cannot handle the request. Somehow I thought that I could just check the Request somehow to get the count of uploaded files. Plus I would love to return a message to the client caller without having to create an exception on the server.

Comment: @Radim - I see your point. It's fair.
Eager to Learn - The problem here is that file upload is an operation where the files are passed in a stream, you have to parse through the stream to figure out what is going on. You can either write the whole stream to disk (as it can potentially be very large), then parse it which will be potentially costlier than catching an exception. Alternatively you can write your own parser that doesn't throw (but that will be uber complex).

Comment: @EagertoLearn Exceptions are costly to be used as a Business validation. Agreed. ;) This is not the case. We are here working with unmanaged sources, external files. We should here explicitly use try-catch because part of this operation is to get a feedback what went wrong and why. E.g. Excpetion of type "unexpected conent" should be handled differently then missing file at all. It is similar if we do access files on a file share... why to break the app if the file is locked. Just inform the user about the issuee. Well ... just my thoughts ;) And really cool guys, that we do discuss that ;) ;)